# Ускорить поиск строк DataGridView

Tags: c#

Всем привет! Как правильно реализовать?

При загрузки формы получаем таблицу из БД MSSQL. Через Task.Run Сделал, чтобы форма не слипалась. Значения сразу после загрузки мне видеть не обязательно.

```
    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Task.Run(new Action(()=> { this.law_ActTableAdapter.Fill(this.dataSet1.Law_Act); }));
    }
```

Вся БД имеет 12 колонок и около 150к строчек ,а так же занимает 390мб памяти процессора(по VS)

Далее , мне необходимо получить только те строки, значения которые похожи на значения из текст боксов.

К примеру: вводим "Ивано" и он выдает нам строки со значением колонки 10: Ивано, Иванов, Иванович, Иваностин и т.д.

Так же и несколько заданных значение, к примеру:

Имя(10 колонка) - Иван
Фамилия(11 колонка) - Ивано
ID(1 колонка) - 3

И DataSet выдает:
3...Иван|Ивано
35..Иван|Иванович
и т.д.

```
    private void search_TextChanged(object sernder, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            
            Search.name = textBox12.Text;

            law_ActBindingSource.Filter = "name like '%{Search.name}%'"

        }
        catch (Exception ex){ MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }
    }
```

Поиск осуществляется по каждому нажатию И в а н о в.

Суть проблема: скорость работы крайне низкая, ведь при нажатии на первую букву поиск будет начинаться по всей таблице заново.

Как можно ускорить этот процесс?

Comment: К запросу можно добавить в конец LIMIT например, чтобы возвращало N первых найденных записей. У вас же не все 150к строк в экран влезает. В зависимости от требований можно подгружать из базы последующие порции строк используя тот же LIMIT.

Comment: @aepot конечно можно поставить лимит, но к примеру мы ищем фамилию Петров или Иванов, а таковых у нас в базе очень много. Если ограничить 10 он может быть 11-м , а если 100, он может быть 101-м :)

Comment: LIMIT позволяет получить порцию не только с начала, там задается и количество и смещение от начала ответа. Например первым запросом можно забрать 0-20, вторым 21-40 и т.д. Грубо говоря, юзер скролит таблицу и по мере прокрутки можно  добрасывать туда строк.

Comment: Представьте, есть например поисковый сервер, и есть у него база данных на 800 терабайт, одна табличка 800 гигов весит. Как вы думаете, если из него попытаться запросить все строки из этой таблицы, кто кто умрет быстрее, клиент или сервер? А если таких клиентов например миллион одновременно с сервером работают? Я говорю о том, что то LIMIT как раз используется для таких ситуаций, и это нормально. Кстати, поизучайте Entity Framework, станет легче такие штуки вытворять.

Comment: @aepot Хорошо. Попробую как тогда правильно реализовать лимит?

Реализовал таким способом

 law_ActBindingSource.Filter = string.Format($"CONVERT(id, System.String) like '%{Search.debt_id}%' LIMIT(10)");

Пишет "отсутствует операнд после оператор LIMIT"

Comment: Да, в MSSQL его нет, я ошибся, но есть аналоги https://stackoverflow.com/questions/603724/how-to-implement-limit-with-sql-server

Comment: А вообще вам обязательно поиск прямо по одной букве сразу делать? Обычно делают так, что ждут пока пользователь перестанет активно набирать текст, т.е. пока пауза после последней нажатой буквы не превысит какой-то временной промежуток - и тогда делают поиск. Это позволяет не забивать сервер бесполезными запросами. Ну, это в дополнение к остальным советам, которые вам уже дали, а не вместо них. Ну и если получается слишком много записей на выходе, может так прямо и говорить пользователю: "слишком много результатов, уточните критерии выборки". Пользователю тоже нафик не сдались тыщи записей.

Comment: @aepot это не мое желание, а требование руководства:) Да, я тоже думал попробовать реализовать такую штуку

Comment: @aepot это все запросы к SQL серверу. С ним то все понятно. Надо все это дело подружить с фильтром. И как я понял он не воспринимает SELECT и т.д.

Comment: Кардинально ускорить запрос могут только индексы (или предварительная сортировка). Однако, на запросе `like '%...%'` индексы не помогут ни в БД, ни в коллекции данных в памяти. / Возможно, типизированная коллекция, наподобие `List<T>` будет чуточку быстрее чем `DataSet`. Поиск при этом осуществлять с помощью `Contains` по свойству. / Чтобы юзер не замечал пауз при вводе очередного символа, поиск осуществлять в отдельном потоке. Лучше вряд ли придумаешь.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov здесь скорее надо шатать требования в ТЗ :)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov пробовал. Не помогает. Вводим букву "П" и у нас выскакивает почти 60к строк подходящих под это дело. Само собой они будут грузится в таблицу нереально долго, а суть - релизовать очень быстрый поиск. Буквально пользователь вводит букву и ему сразу выдает все строки , где в условной фамилии есть такая буква(в данном случае в начале) и если с фамилией можно реализовать что то типо "family like '%...%' " , то с ID такое уже не прокатит

 Вот серьезно задумал по поводу LIMIT'a , реализация никак не выходит.

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону [виртуального режима](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.virtualmode?view=windowsdesktop-5.0) датагрида. [Walkthrough](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/implementing-virtual-mode-wf-datagridview-control?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8). Слева в меню смотрите другие статьи документации.